# Pandas: removing whitespace from column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove multiple spaces aka whitespace from my dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv(Location + sicht_orig, delimiter = ';', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", decimal = ",", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Just to be sure that I have the data type 'object', i.e. string:

```
print(df['column_name'].dtypes)
```

Now I used strip to remove the whitespace:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip()
print(df['column_name'])
```

Sadly, all the whitespace is still there.

Alternative approach:

```
print (getattr (row, "Description").str.strip('  '))
```

gives:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I have also tried without success:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Any thought for my beginner's mind would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the output of "print(df.dtypes)" . O/p for whole df and not a particular column.

Comment: Thanks Raj! This is what print(df.dtypes) shows:
Date           datetime64[ns]
    Amount                float64
    Category               object
    Tags                   object
    Description            object
    Account                object
    dtype: object_